# radius_cm is not a valid plot or backend keyword argument.Possible backend keyword arguments for ipywidgets are:['width_cm', height_cm','display']

Tags: exception, backend, ipywidgets

I am new to python and running someone else's code to analyze electrophysiology datasets. When I run the code

```
w = sw.plot_unit_templates(we, radius_um =30, backend="ipywidgets")
```

I get this error `Exception: radius_cm is not a valid plot argument or backend keyword argument. Possible backend keyword arguments for ipywidgets are : ['width_cm','height_cm', 'display']`. Not sure if this is because a different version of ipywidgets than the person who wrote the codes or python version mismatch. I am using Python 3.10. I will appreciate any solutions to this.

Thanks!

the expected output for this is action potential waveforms [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bav3g.png)